# MySQL Sort by multiple columns (3) with some specific rules

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

the question has been posted but marked as duplicate. Please note
that I am aware of simple `ORDER BY` with multiple columns and with a
window function `MIN()` for example for a simple case of
two columns.

Suppose I have a table so-called `Contact` (Table 1.) What I want to
achieve is to sort first by `Status` than within the result, sort
`Client` by `CalledAt` (keep `Client` close together by `CreatedAt`
while keeping the order of `Client` as-is from the first sort)

Bellow my explanation, please suggest a better question/explanation if
it makes things clearer.

Thank you,

Step 0:

| ID | User | Client | CalledAt | Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | B | Y | 2022-02-07 | Do not answer |
| 2 | A | Y | 2022-02-09 | Answer |
| 3 | A | X | 2022-02-08 | Answer |
| 4 | B | X | 2022-02-10 | Do not answer |
| 5 | A | X | 2022-02-06 | Answer |
| 6 | B | Z | 2022-02-11 | Do not answer |

Step 1: Sort by Status

| ID | User | Client | CalledAt | Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | A | Y | 2022-02-09 | Answer |
| 3 | A | X | 2022-02-08 | Answer |
| 5 | A | X | 2022-02-06 | Answer |
| 1 | B | Y | 2022-02-07 | Do not answer |
| 4 | B | X | 2022-02-10 | Do not answer |
| 6 | B | Z | 2022-02-11 | Do not answer |

Now the list of clients are: `YXXYXZ`, I want to keep the client `Y`
first, because it appeared first in the list then `X` because it appeared first after all the `Y` then `Z`...

The list of clients should be `YYXXXZ`. Within the client, they should be sorted by `CreatedAt`.

Step 2: Line 1 is moved above line 2 becase it shares the same client `Y`
but with a smaller (sonner) `CalledAt`. Line 5 is moved above line 3 and
line 4 is move bellow line 3

| ID | User | Client | CalledAt | Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | B | Y | 2022-02-07 | Do not answer |
| 2 | A | Y | 2022-02-09 | Answer |
| 5 | A | X | 2022-02-06 | Answer |
| 3 | A | X | 2022-02-08 | Answer |
| 4 | B | X | 2022-02-10 | Do not answer |
| 6 | B | Z | 2022-02-11 | Do not answer |

Comment: Please add your desired output as text.

Comment: @P.Salmon The desired output IS there, as text

Comment: Why not just `ORDER BY Client, CalledAt`?

Comment: The desired output is the Table 3 @MattBailie

Comment: It's not ORDER BY Client, CalledAt because the client `Y` is appeared before client `X` according to the rules

Comment: No, there is nothing to explain why client Y comes first. In step one you sort by status only, any of the three rows could come first. Did you mean that the first step should sort by status, id? Or something else? (Please also specify if you're using MySQL 5.x or MySQL 8)

Comment: The clients in the Table 2 are `Y, X, X, Y, X, Z`. I want to keep the first occurence of each client before other client, so the list should be: `Y, Y, X, X, X, Z`. Within the same client they should be sorted by CreatedAt. I tend to use the term "grouping" of Client here but it's not correct and confusing

Comment: I don't get what the rules are, when you sort by status the order will be kep

Comment: Sorry for the confusing explanation. The first sort by `Status` allows us to find the first occurence of each "group" of client. Please note that "group" has nothing todo with MySQL "GROUP BY", they just mean the clients are kept close tother without an explicit sort (ASC or DESC because they're not)

Comment: As per my first comment; ***Please also specify if you're using MySQL 5.x or MySQL 8.***

Comment: What I can imagine is to SELECT DISTINCT all the clients with Status ORDER (Y, X, Z) then UNION all SELECT with CreatedAt ORDER and with Client equal to Y, X, Z. But then it's almost impossible to do proper paging

Comment: I'm using MySQL 5.7 but I'm open to migrate to MySQL8/MariaDB if there is no other solution

Comment: My paraphrase of your requirements; clients with at least one Answer status row come before clients with no Answer status rows, then the client with the lowest id in its rows comes first, then each client's rows are sorted by timestamp

Comment: Yes, and no: There should be more than 2 Statuses. ID doesn't count. The rules are (1) Sort by Status, find all the occurrences of Client, in our case are Y, X, and Z. (2) Select all the rows with client = Y, sorted by CreatedAt then with client = X, sorted by CreatedAt then Z, sorted by CreatedAt

Comment: ID ***must*** count, otherwise there's no reason for Y to be before X!

Comment: You're right. I tend to say that's it's natural sort but in our case ID does matter

Comment: There is ***NO*** natural sort in SQL. If you need a particular order it ***must*** be specified.

Comment: Thank you, min(id) is what's I was missing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL 5.x

```
SELECT
  yourTable.*
FROM
  yourTable
INNER JOIN
(
  SELECT
    client,
    MIN(id)       AS min_id,
    MIN(Status)   AS min_status
  FROM
    yourTable
  GROUP BY
    client
)
  AS client
    ON client.client = yourTable.client
ORDER BY
  client.min_status,
  client.min_id,
  yourTable.calledAt
```